# CodeIgniter update funciona mas lista errado

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Estou tendo um problema na hora de atualizar um registro do banco pelo codeigniter, tenho duas tabelas, uma chamada:

**empregado(onde é armazenado os funcionários da empresa e em qual setor esse funcionário trabalha,esta tabela tem a chave estrangeira da tabela setor(id_setor)**

E a outra chamada:
 **setor(onde armazena os setores da empresa)**

Consigo atualizar as informações pelos formulários sem dar erro, inclusive atualiza no banco também, porem, a listagem no sistema mostra o setor antigo do empregado e não o novo recém atualizado, por exemplo:

**João da silva - Arrecadação,
atualizo para administração(atualiza no banco o novo setor)
quando dou o redirect para a listagem do sistema e o João da Silva ainda esta no setor arrecadação.**

Código do modelo empregado,onde eu faço a junção das tabelas(setor e empregado),para mostrar os nomes dos setores da listagem do sistema

```
public function ListarEmpregado(){
$this->db->select('e.id_empregado, e.nome_empregado,e.salario, s.nome');
$this->db->from('empregado as e');
$this->db->join('setor as s','s.id_setor = e.id_empregado');
$this->db->order_by('nome_empregado');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Codigo de update do empregado(modelo empregado):

```
public function atualizarinfosempregado($id,$array){
    $this->db->where('id_empregado',$id);
    $this->db->update('empregado',$array);  
}
```

Listagem(index_empresa.php):

```
<?php foreach($empregado as $e){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $e->id_empregado ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $e->nome_empregado ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $e->salario ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $e->nome ?></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="empregado" id="<?php echo $e->id_empregado; ?>">Deletar</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.3/CodeIgniter-3.1.3/index.php/IndexController/idempregado/<?php echo $e->id_empregado; ?>">Atualizar</a></td>
        </tr>
```

O que será que esta faltando?
Agradeço pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema está no *join* que está sendo feito na consulta, você está fazendo o *join* de `id_setor` com `id_empregado`, segue abaixo como deveria ser feito:

```
public function ListarEmpregado(){
    $this->db->select('e.id_empregado, e.nome_empregado,e.salario, s.nome');
    $this->db->from('empregado as e');
    $this->db->join('setor as s','s.id_setor = e.id_setor');
    $this->db->order_by('nome_empregado');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Funcionou,era um errinho bem bobo
muito obrigado